# VB JSON without key value

Tags: json, vb.net

Another JSON query..

I have data in a table which I need to serialize but I do not want to show the key, just the value..  I am currently using this code which gives both key and value..

```
Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
     row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
     For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
         row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
     Next
     rows.Add(row)
Next
Dim X = serializer.Serialize(rows)
Return
```

Which gives me `{"field1" : "data1", "field2" : "data2"},
{"field1" : "data1", "field2" : "data2"},
{"field1" : "data1", "field2" : "data2"}`

But I'd like `{"data1","data2},{"data1","data2},{"data1","data2}`

Can anyone advise..

Thank you in advance..

Comment: when serializing, all the serializers will include the property name or in this case key so the object can be deserialized.  you could try just serializing the ValueCollection

Comment: Thank you Plutonix..   I don't suppose you could give me a hint as to what to do?  I can't find much help online regarding the ValueCollections and how to use it..  Thanks again..

Comment: Thinking further I think I will have to bud the JSON myself if I am only looking to put the values in it..  Thank you for replying though Plutonix..

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET Utility Class to Serialize Deserialize Json String

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

''' <summary>
''' JSON Serialization and Deserialization Assistant ClassS
''' </summary>
Public Class JsonHelper
    ''' <summary>
    ''' JSON Serialization
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared Function JsonSerializer(Of T)(ByVal obj As T) As String
    Dim ser As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(T))
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    ser.WriteObject(ms, obj)
    Dim jsonString As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray())
    ms.Close()
    'Replace Json Date String                                         
    Dim p As String = "\\/Date\((\d+)\+\d+\)\\/"
    Dim matchEvaluator As New MatchEvaluator(AddressOf ConvertJsonDateToDateString)
    Dim reg As New Regex(p)
    jsonString = reg.Replace(jsonString, matchEvaluator)
    Return jsonString
End Function

''' <summary>
''' JSON Deserialization
''' </summary>
Public Shared Function JsonDeserialize(Of T)(ByVal jsonString As String) As T
    'Convert "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" String as "\/Date(1319266795390+0800)\/"
    Dim p As String = "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}"
    Dim matchEvaluator As New MatchEvaluator(AddressOf ConvertDateStringToJsonDate)
    Dim reg As New Regex(p)
    jsonString = reg.Replace(jsonString, matchEvaluator)
    Dim ser As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(T))
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString))
    Dim obj As T = DirectCast(ser.ReadObject(ms), T)
    Return obj
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Convert Serialization Time /Date(1319266795390+0800) as String
''' </summary>
Private Shared Function ConvertJsonDateToDateString(ByVal m As Match) As String
    Dim result As String = String.Empty
    Dim dt As New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)
    dt = dt.AddMilliseconds(Long.Parse(m.Groups(1).Value))
    dt = dt.ToLocalTime()
    result = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    Return result
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Convert Date String as Json Time
''' </summary>
Private Shared Function ConvertDateStringToJsonDate(ByVal m As Match) As String
    Dim result As String = String.Empty
    Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(m.Groups(0).Value)
    dt = dt.ToUniversalTime()
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = dt - DateTime.Parse("1970-01-01")
    result = String.Format("\/Date({0}+0800)\/", ts.TotalMilliseconds)
    Return result
End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Also

Here is the easiest way to deserialize JSON into an object (using .NET 4):

```
Dim j As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Object)(JSONString)
```

Then, depending on the structure of the new object, you can retrieve the data like so:

```
 r.status = j("status")
 r.legs= j("routes")(0)("legs")
```

***and more detailed solution*** :

I'd recommend you to use ***JavaScriptSerializer*** over *DataContractJsonSerializer*. The reasons are:

- *JavaScriptSerializer* is faster over DataContractJsonSerializer
- *DataContractJsonSerializer* requires more code than JavaScriptSerializer for a simple serialization.

You won't need the DataContract and DataMember attribute to use along with JavaScriptSerializer

Use this data class

```
 <Serializable> _
 Public Class ApplicationItem
Public Property application_id() As String
    Get
        Return m_application_id
    End Get
    Set
        m_application_id = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_application_id As String
Public Property application_package() As String
    Get
        Return m_application_package
    End Get
    Set
        m_application_package = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_application_package As String
 End Class
```

And use this to deserialize your jsonText:

```
 Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
 Dim dict = jss.Deserialize(Of List(Of ApplicationItem))(jsonText)
```

If you still want to use DataContractJsonSerializer, you can use this code below to deserialize:

```
 Dim obj As New List(Of ApplicationItem)()
 Dim ms As New MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json))
 Dim serializer As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.[GetType]())
 obj = DirectCast(serializer.ReadObject(ms), List(Of ApplicationItem))
 ms.Close()
 ms.Dispose()
```